# Cómo agregar un marcador sin necesidad de recargar la pestaña - Google maps api v3

Tags: php, google-maps, codeigniter

Utilizo PHP con el Framework CodeIgniter 3.1.0 conectándome a PHPMYADMIN 10.1.13-*****. Por ende, deseo que cuando se inserte en la base de datos la latitud y la longitud de un marcador nuevo, se vea inmediatamente reflejado en la aplicación web, sin necesidad de recargar la pestaña.

VISTA

```
<script>
    //Marcadores
    var neighborhoods = [
<?php if (count($locations) != 0) { ?>
    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($locations); $i++) { ?>
        <?php for ($f = 0; $f < count($locations[$i]); $f++) { ?>
                {lat: <?= $locations[$i][$f]['lat'] ?>, lng: <?= $locations[$i][$f]['lng'] ?>, km: <?= $locations[$i][$f]['km'] ?>, fecha: <?= $locations[$i][$f]['km'] ?>}<?php if (count($locations) != $i) { ?>,<?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
    ];
            function initMap() {
                //CARGO MAPA CON UN CENTRO
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: <?= $center['0']['lat'] ?>, lng: <?= $center['0']['lng'] ?>},
                    zoom: 17
                });

                // LINEA
                var flightPlanCoordinates = neighborhoods;
                var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
                    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
                    geodesic: true,
                    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
                    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });
                flightPath.setMap(map);
                //FIN LINEA   
            }  

</script>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />
<div id="map"></div>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MI_CLAVE&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Trataré de ser lo más breve y específico posible. Le comento que estoy trabajando en una aplicación de traking por gps y se me produce el siguiente problema: - cuando intento actualizar el marcador de posición este se me actualiza, pero también se me actualiza el mapa completo (perdiendo el zoom que había realizado y mostrándome nuevamente los continentes completos). Entonces, como puedo hacer para actualizar sólo los marcadores de posición, pero sin que se recarga el mapa cada vez que actualizo.

Comment: Hola tratare de ser lo más breve y específico posible. Le comento que estoy trabajando en una aplicación de traking por gps y se me produce el siguiente problema:
- cuando intento actualizar el marcador de posición este se me actualiza, pero también se me actualiza el mapa completo (perdiendo el zoom que había  realizado y mostrándome nuevamente los continentes completos). 

Entonces, como puedo hacer para actualizar sólo los marcadores de posición, pero sin que se recarga el mapa cada vez que actualizo. 

Desde ya muchas gracias. 

Saludos, 

Isaías Díaz

Comment: Como puedo colocar mas caracteres en mi caso HTML y PHP, a un nuevo comentario ??

Comment: Estimado como puedo escribir mas caracteres especificados, o me puede dar su correo, y no puedo usar el botón "{ }" o Ctrl+K, para agregar codigo.

Comment: Ver esta imagen de ayuda: https://i.stack.imgur.com/urUrW.png

Comment: Ya agregue el código de la vista a mi consulta, espero que les sirva para resolver mi inquietud.

Comment: Una consulta, considero que lo que pido creo que ustedes lo hacen en el código, es decir ustedes me muestran "Hace 1 minuto" luego sin recargar la pestaña o pagina muestra "Hace 5 minuto" . Entonces como lo hacen ?? con que tecnología o que lenguaje de programación lo hacen ??

Comment: Han visto mi edición de código ??

Comment: Ya he editado mi código, como puedo resolverlo ??

Comment: Isaías: Has colocado en comentarios información que debería ir en el cuerpo de la pregunta, pero los comentarios son para otra cosa. Los detalles en http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment. Cabe resaltar que redacar correctamente una pregunta te da mayores probabilidades de que alguien se interese en responderla. Artículo de ayuda relacionado [ask].

Answer (score 2):

En tu implementación, la declaración de los markers se está escribiendo inline mediante PHP. No tienes cómo refrescarla sin refrescar la página.

Lo que debieras hacer, en cambio, es tener un endpoint únicamente para entregar el contenido de los markers:

```
<?php

$neighborhoods = [];
if (count($locations) != 0) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($locations); $i++) { 
    for ($f = 0; $f < count($locations[$i]); $f++) { 
      $neighborhoods[]=[
         'lat'=> $locations[$i][$f]['lat'], 
         'lng'=> $locations[$i][$f]['lng'], 
         'km'=>$locations[$i][$f]['km'], 
         'fecha'=> $locations[$i][$f]['fecha']
      ];
    }
  }
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($neighborhoods);
```

Y en vez de asumir que la variable neighborhoods está presente en la página, debes pedirla a este endpoint mediante ajax, y refrescar tu polilínea de acuerdo al resultado obtenido.

```
function initMap() {
  //CARGO MAPA CON UN CENTRO
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), { 
          center: { 
            lat: <?= $center['0']['lat'] ?>, 
            lng: <?= $center['0']['lng'] ?>
          },zoom: 17 });

  jQuery.ajax({
     url:'neighborhoods.php'
     dataType:'json'
  }).then(function(neighborhoods) {

    // LINEA
    var flightPlanCoordinates = neighborhoods;
    var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
    //FIN LINEA   
  });
}
```

Podrías, por ejemplo, asociar un botón para gatillar ese evento ajax después de la carga inicial, redibujando la polilínea acorde a lo que te entregó el endpoint. Como la polilínea ya existe, sólo tendrías que usar el método `setPath(neighborhoods)` para que ésta dibuje los nuevos puntos